# R: Pushing entire row to NA based on condition in one column at a time

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, variable-assignment, na

Assume df:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   10  NA  10  NA  10
10  NA  10  1   10  10
10  1   1   NA  NA  NA
10  10  NA  10  10  10
10  NA  10  10  1   10
```

What I wish to do is to loop through columns to check values for each rows with following conditions:

- A < 5 or NA
- C < 3 or NA
- E < 7 or NA
- F < 2 or NA

...and subsequently, with rows in the looped column matching respective condition, the entire row will be pushed to NA

Desired outcome:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
10  NA  10  1   10  10
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I tried doing this to one of the columns:

```
df[df$A<5, ] <- NA
```

However this caused the error of

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df$A < 5, , value = NA) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

Please advise

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry for the typo as I accidentally posted the question in midst of editing by clicking enter, I have fixed the typo. Error still exists however...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just assign `NA` after subsetting the rows you don't want.

```
df[with(df,A<5 | C<3 | E<7 | F<2 |
           is.na(A) | is.na(C) | is.na(E) | is.na(F)),] <- NA
df
#   A  B  C  D  E  F
#1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
#2 10 NA 10  1 10 10
#3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
#4 NA NA NA NA NA NA
#5 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

The approach is to create a logical vector for each of your conditions for every row, and then combine them with `|` (or). Then you can subset `df` with that logical vector to only replace the rows that meet the condition with `NA`.

Using `with` keeps you from having to type out `df$` 8 times.

---

Depending on how many conditions you have in your real data, you might be able to make it more compact with `Reduce`, but perhaps not:

```
df[with(df,Reduce(`|`,c(list(A<5, C<3, E<7, F<2),
                        lapply(list(A,C,E,F),is.na)))),] <- NA
```

Comment: I had a similar `Map` + `Reduce` idea in `dat[-which(!Reduce(\`|\`, Map(\`<\`, dat[vars], c(5,3,7,2)))),] <- NA` which I think works implicitly with the `NA`

Comment: Hmmm, I like this. I would upvote if you wrote an answer. ;)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it works for all cases, but I will return to it when I have a moment.

Comment: Maybe something like ```df[-which(Reduce(`&`, Map(`>`,with(df,list(A,C,E,F)),c(5,3,7,2)))),] <- NA```.

Answer (score 4):

You can use some `tidyverse` manipulation

```r
library(dplyr)

df_example <- data.table::fread("A   B   C   D   E   F
1   10  NA  10  NA  10
10  NA  10  1   10  10
10  1   1   NA  NA  NA
10  10  NA  10  10  10
10  NA  10  10  1   10")

df_example %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(.x))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(exclude = any(c_across(c(A,C,E,F)) %>% is.na() | A < 5 | C < 3 | E < 7 | F < 2)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), .fns = ~ ifelse(exclude == TRUE, yes = NA, .x))) %>%
  select(-exclude) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>       A     B     C     D     E     F
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 2    10    NA    10     1    10    10
#> 3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```